# ActionView::Template::Error (highcharts.js isn't precompiled):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionview

my app on heroku shows this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (highcharts.js isn't precompiled):
```

I tried two solutions I found on internet

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

and

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

I read a post (I don't remember which) and create de heroku with this command:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

also when I run heroku open I got this error:

[image]

here is my heroku logs

```
....
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (highcharts.js isn't precompiled):
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"  %>
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= javascript_include_tag :highcharts %>
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: </head>
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: <body>
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4426161850966429466_47229900'
2012-08-08T21:03:41+00:00 heroku[router]: GET floating-forest-7331.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4010ms status=304 bytes=0
....
```

EDIT if you wanna see my app (I would appreciate that you check it) here is my [github](https://github.com/asantoya/tankinlog)

Comment: I found this [possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198856/heroku-js-isnt-precompiled-error/11873883#11873883) but really I don't understand so much

Answer (score 0):

Please, try:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then add the created folder `./public/assets/` to your Git repository and push to Heroku.

---

If rake will try to connect to your database, add in your `./config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

---

[Precompiling Assets @ guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: I got this error: 

rake aborted!
FATAL:  database "db/estation_test_production" does not exist

Comment: @Asantoya17 I've added in my answer possible solution to your current problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I posted that solution I already tried that command line

Comment: @Asantoya17 And have you tried assets:precompile after applying this configuration setting?